# adobe flash plugin not working after being updated

Tags: adobe

I updated the adobe flash plug-in from the Synaptic package manager.
The updation wasn't successful.
After that i started to experience issues with adobe flash plugin in browsers, i was not able to watch videos on youtube.
Now when i open synaptic manager it gives an error
run command **"sudo dpkg --configure -a"** in terminal.

when i run the command in terminal, it gives me an error,

**"unable to fsync updated status of "hicolor-icon-theme": input/output error"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do: (Im assuming you have flash 11 and firefox 14.0.1):

1. Download this file : http://www.ziddu.com/download/20225702/libflashplayer.zip.html
2. Create a folder "plugins" under "/home/YOUR-USER-NAME/.mozilla/firefox/"

   Like this:  /home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins
3. Extract the zip and copy the downloaded "libflashplayer.so" to "/home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins"
4. Open nautilus as Admin. Go to "/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin". Delete the "libflashplayer.so" there.
5. Copy the extracted "libflashplayer.so" there.
6. Restart firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with adobe flash.  I`m using lxde with a different icon theme than the original, and when I switched back to the original theme the problem went away. Hope that this can help.